# Do we need to create SqliteOpenHelper as Singleton Class in android

Tags: android, sqlite

It is thread safe to use single instance of database by all activities of my Applications. And if i do so, when should i close the database connection.
Please recommend the right method to use SqliteOpenHelper .

Comment: You don't need to close the DB.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888530/is-it-ok-to-have-one-instance-of-sqliteopenhelper-shared-by-all-activities-in-an

Answer (score 0):

I've been using an approach I found in an online course and haven't had a slightest issue with it. Just put a **synchronized** keyword for your database instance so that multiple threads could manage it at the same time. This is what I am using:

```
synchronized static AppDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new AppDatabase(context.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return (instance);
}
```